# Why sub() can not perform a string substitution?

Tags: jq

I don't understand why the `sub()` command does not replace "%s" with "my string" in the first jq command below. How to make it work?

```
$ jq -r --arg format '|%s|' '$format | sub("%s"; .desc)' <<< '{"desc": "my string"}'
||
$ jq -r --arg format '|%s|' '$format | sub("%s"; "my string")' <<< '{"x": "y"}'
|my string|
$ jq -r .desc <<< '{"desc": "my string"}'
my string
```

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: Same as the 2nd one.

Comment: In the first one, you use `$format.desc` as the second parameter of `sub`

Answer (score 1):

You have lost the input context. Save it in a variable (eg. `. as $dot`) to reference it later (eg. `$dot.desc`):

```sh
$ jq -r --arg format '|%s|' '. as $dot | $format | sub("%s"; $dot.desc)' <<< '{"desc": "my string"}'
|my string|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use null input `-n` :

```
jq -nr --arg format '|%s|' '$format | sub("%s"; input.desc)' <<< '{"desc": "my string"}'
```